# android : how can I store an audio file in the application folder

Tags: android, audio-player

I am using StatusBarNotification in my application. I want to play some particular sound when the notification arrives. So I planned to store the sound file in the application folder. But I am not sure, where to store this .mp3 file. Is it within the res folder? I and also I want to know how to play this file from the application.

Please help me...

Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to store this in the /res/raw folder.  Take a look at this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: thank you so much.. but in the document , it is saying that, we can play a file in the raw folder using Uri. But in the StatusBarNotification, we can customise the sound only using Uri. Please tell me how it is possible?

Comment: You should be able to access your /res/raw resource with a Uri with something like: notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackagename.appname/" + R.raw.your_sound_file);